# Why some special characters are not supported in one signal?

Tags: web-services, push-notification, onesignal

I am using onesignal to send push notifications to mobile app from my webservice. but I realized that some characters are not supported, what can we do to resolve this issue? below is my postString sent to onesignal:

```
     postString = "{""app_id"":""myID"",""language"":""ar"", ""tags"" : 
     [{""key"": ""my_key"", ""relation"": ""="", ""value"": """ & my_value& """}] ,
     ""data"" : {""contactName"" : """ & contactName & """ }, 
     ""contents"" : {""en"" : """ & pushMessage & """ } }"
```

when I tried to send data like `+-*/.!@#$%^&*()_+=-?><|":;'\` I got this error:
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
NB: When I changed language to en I got the same error. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All unicode characters are supported. It's possible that the extra quote in your data caused this issue. Please make sure that your postString is in a valid JSON by escaping any single or double quotes and that should resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your declaration, I realized that the problem was only whenever I want to send " ' or \