# Issue sending push notifications with accent (á,é,í) through OneSignal

Tags: java, onesignal

Whenever I try to send push notifications with accent (á,é,í) through OneSignal, I get the null symbol on my phone.

Comment: You have probably invalid JSON message:
<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847613/why-some-special-characters-are-not-supported-in-one-signal

Comment: please add more information about your request (your request)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue encoding my message as `UTF-8`:

```
String payload   =   "{"
   + "\"app_id\": \"" + APP_ID + "\","
   + "\"filters\": [{\"field\": \"tag\", \"key\": \"company\", \"relation\": \"=\", \"value\": \"" + companyID + "\"}],"
   + "\"data\": {\"foo\": \"bar\"},"
   + "\"contents\": {\"en\": \" " + notification + "\"}"
   + "}";

byte[] data = payload.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

I also set the Content-Type as `application/json; charset=UTF-8`.